# Ubuntu 21.04. Размер диска. Подскажите плиз

Tags: ubuntu

Пытался разобраться, но что-то не выходит.
Сам родом из FreeBSD а тут убунта.
Короче говоря, установил на виртуалку Убунту.
диск 40Гигов.
Начинаю настраивать LAMP стек.
Ту замечаю что диск не 40 Гигов а 20ть.

```
root@uboonto:/dev# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              389M  2.1M  387M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   20G   19G   18M 100% /
tmpfs                              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda2                         976M  250M  660M  28% /boot
tmpfs                              389M  4.0K  389M   1% /run/user/1000
```

хм.. говорю я и начинаю смотреть дальше

```
root@uboonto:/dev# parted /dev/xvda
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /dev/xvda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: Xen Virtual Block Device (xvd)
Disk /dev/xvda: 42.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  1076MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1076MB  42.9GB  41.9GB
```

```
parted /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 21.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  21.5GB  21.5GB  ext4
(parted) q
```

Подскажите плиз, есть решения заиметь оставшиеся 20Гигов?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может виртуалка забирает, или делает некоторый "запас"

Comment: вывод `$ sudo pvs` приложите, пожалуйста.